# what is the difference between cts, fn and xdmp functions in Marklogic?

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-10

I am beginner in Marklogic learning. I tried checking over the internet the difference but i don't see anything. Sorry if it's a silly question. what actually is the difference?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The prefix for those methods are bound to different namespaces. The namespace indicates the category, purpose, and "owner".

- `fn` are the standard XQuery, XPath, and XSLT functions (in this namespace: http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions). You can expect them to be available in any standard XQuery, XPath, and XSLT engine.

  - http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions
  - https://docs.marklogic.com/fn
- `cts` functions are the MarkLogic **C**ore **T**ext **S**earch built-in functions (in this namespace: http://marklogic.com/cts). They are a set of MarkLogic specific functions that are used for search and query operations.

  - http://marklogic.com/cts
- `xdmp` functions are the MarkLogic **X**ML **D**atabase **M**anagement **P**latform built-in functions (in this namespace: http://marklogic.com/xdmp). They are a set of MarkLogic custom functions that provide extra utility functions and MarkLogic database specific actions.

  - http://marklogic.com/xdmp

The full set of functions available in MarkLogic, broken out by category and namespace

- XQuery: https://docs.marklogic.com/all
- JavaScript: https://docs.marklogic.com/js/all

Comment: Thanks! Your answer deserves a place in MarkLogic documentation. I searched through MarkLogic website and couldn't find "XML Database Management Platform" anywhere.