# What is the full form of xdmp ? Context - XDMP function in Marklogic Server

Tags: marklogic

Can anyone please let me know the full form of XDMP in XDMP function, which is used in Marklogic?

Comment: You should check out another great answer by Mads here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64503476/3546482

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**XDMP** is an acronym for MarkLogic **X**ML **D**atabase **M**anagement **P**latform.

The XDMP built-in functions are bound to the namespace: http://marklogic.com/xdmp. They are a set of MarkLogic custom functions that provide extra utility functions and MarkLogic database specific actions.

https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp

Comment: Thank you Mads .